# strictly convex functions and limits

Tags: limits, convex-analysis

Suppose I have a strictly convex function $f(x)$ for $x\geq 0$, with $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) =0$ and $f''(0) >0$.  Is it obvious that $f$ must be superlinear as $x\to +\infty$?  Alternatively, how can I conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = +\infty
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = x -\ln (1+x)$ is a counterexample. More generally, let $g:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be any strictly increasing continuous function such that $g(0)=0, g'(0) > 0$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty}g(t)<\infty.$ Then $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\,dt$ is a counterexample. (That's how I found $x -\ln (1+x);$ it's the integral of $t/(t+1).$)

Comment: It's interesting that in both your example and the other answer, the limit $f(x) / x$ as $x \to \infty$ is not zero. That's a weaker statement than what OP wanted, but it seems like it is probably true? Or can someone come up with an example where the limit is 0?

Comment: Any counterexample $f$ must have $\lim f(x)/x >0.$ (Note; Convexity implies $f(x)/x$ is increasing, so the limit will exist if we allow $\infty$ as a limit.) The reason is $f'(0) = 0,f''(0) > 0.$ This tells us $f'(x_0)> 0$ for some $x_0$ near $0.$ But the line tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is under the graph of $f$ on $(x_0,\infty)$ by convexity. Hence $\lim f(x)/x \ge f'(x_0).$

Answer (score 2):

You can’t. Consider

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}-1\;;$$

clearly $f(0)=0$. Now

$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\;,$$

so $f'(0)=0$, and

$$f''(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{1+x^2}=\frac{1+2x^2}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}>0$$

for all $x$, but

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

The claim is true for **strongly** convex function, but not generally true for **strictly** convex functions. The -ve result for **strictly** convex functions is proved by @Brian M. Scott's counter-example. For strongly convex functions, indeed one would have

\begin{eqnarray}
\exists m > 0\text{ s.t }f(x) \ge f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + \frac{m}{2}x^2 = \frac{m}{2}x^2, \forall x
\end{eqnarray}
from which it would follow $\underset{x \rightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim }}\frac{f(x)}{x} = +\infty$.

**N.B.:** In the above definition of strong convexity, the **global** constant $m > 0$ is called a *modulus of strong convexity* for $f$. In @Brian M. Scott's counter-example (as well as any other counter-example) for the strict convexity case, we won't be able to globally lower-bound $f''$ by a positive constant :)